# How can I keep the JavaFX 7 skin with JavaFX 8?

Tags: styles, javafx, look-and-feel, javafx-8, java-8

JavaFX 8 introduces a new look and feel by default, but I want to keep the default JavaFX 7 type style for my application (whilst using Java 8.)

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put:

```
setUserAgentStylesheet(STYLESHEET_CASPIAN);
```

...as the first line of your program (in the `start()` method), or run it with the JVM flag `-Djavafx.userAgentStylesheetUrl=caspian`.

Note the above method isn't present in JavaFX 2.x, so if you want to do this in code that compiles and runs on both Java 7 and 8, unfortunately the only way around it is via reflection.